# Confused with the complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

Im trying to find the time complexity of  max1 and max2.

```
def max1(L,left,right):
    if left==right:
        return L[left]
    return max(L[left], max1(L,left+1,right))

def max2(L, left, right):
    if left==right:
        return L[left]
    mid = (left+right)//2
    l = max2(L, left, mid)
    r = max2(L, mid+1, right)
    return max(l,r)

def max_list(L):
    return max1(L,0,len(L)-1)# or max2(L,0,len(L)-1)
```

From how I see it is that Max1:
depth is O(n). Each level of the recursion we do O(n-k). so overall the complexity is O(n^2). I read somewhere that the comlexity here is O(n). who's right?

max2:
depth is O(logn). Each step I do O(1) for every list and overal each step O(n)
so I think Max2 is O(n)*O(logn)= O(nlogn). Somehow I read that it is O(n). so who's right?

Comment: can you please give a brief explanation?

Comment: for max1, each level you do O(1) once, not O(n-k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its important to define recursion complexity in terms of recurrence relations.

For your first algorithm, you have

`T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)`

Which means you do some constant amount of work, and decrease the size of your set by 1 and recursively call yourself. This will yield a recursion tree of depth `n`, where each parent only has one child (you can think of it as a straight line), which you can see would be O(n) because of the constant amount of work.

[image]

For the second algorithm, you have

`T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)`

Saying you split your input in half and call recursively twice, and do some constant amount of work. This scenario you can use the [master thereom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) to show it is `O(n)`.